# Compressing to NPOT image to POT PVR without scaling

Tags: pvrtc

I have images of various sizes and I would like to convert them to PVR POT images but PVRTexTool is only able to rescale image to POT and I don't see any option to do that with Apples's texturetool.

What I want to get is POT image with original image embedded inside, keeping its original size so no scaling occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly this answer is a little late, but I notice that at least the last version of PVRTexTool can resize the canvas of textures in the GUI and via the "rcanvas" or "potcanvas" option of the command line version. I think this will do what you want.

Another option would be to use its mirrored border functionality which would have the advantage of adding texels of the same colours around the edge of your original image and could help avoid any PVRTC border effects that you might still get with the resize option. This option has been in PVRTexTool for a few years IIRC.

I'm interested in what advantage you think that padding the image would have versus scaling the images to POT and then shrinking them on render(?).